# Plotting lines between coordinates using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the connecting lines for different sets of coordinates found in a file with the following format:(both coordinates have the same Y-value but different X-values)

Y1   X11   X12
Y2   X21   X22
Y3   X31   X32
.
.
.

I was able to find a way to do it using segments() in r. Since plotting the lines for those coordinates will produce thousands of lines, I would like to use ggplot2 for giving alpha levels to the line colors in order to check those areas in the plot that have a greater number of superimposed lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

#some data
df<-data.frame(y=1:1000,x1=sample(1:100.1000,replace=T))
df$x2<-df$x1+sample(5:10,1000,replace=T)

ggplot()  + geom_segment(data=df,aes(x = x1, y = y, xend = x2, yend = y),colour="red",alpha=0.5)
```